# Prawn - Rails 5.2 Put two bits of text on the same line but at either side

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn

I've been trying to replicate the text style in the following example:

[image: text format example]

But I havn't been able to find a way to put two text elements on the same line.

Is this possible with Prawn?  If so how does one do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use prawn-table, your image looks like a table with 2 columns.

https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn-table

```
table([
  ["Base Price", "$275,99],
  ["Canary Cozy Sound Isolation Blankey", "$11.00"]
])
```

You will have to play, of course, with the style of the table to remove borders, the alignment of the cells for the second column, etc.